# Does there exist a closed subspace $B$ of a Banach space $X$ with countable infinite codimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Assume I have a Banach space $X$ and a closed subspace $B$. My question is: is it possible that the codimension of $B$ is exactly $\aleph_0$? If so, what is an example? If not, why?

The codimention of $B$ can of course be finite or uncountable, as we can just take the direct sum of two Banach spaces with the appropriate dimension. This of course doesn’t work for the case of my question, as there are no Banach space with countable dimension. It is also clear that such a Banach subspace can’t be complemented (for the same reason).

I am not that expert, the answer might be quite simple, but I can’t find a solution to this at the moment and I have not found similar questions here on
SE, so I thought might be interesting for other people.

Comment: $X/B$ is also a Banach space, so this is impossible.

Comment: You are right, it was so easy. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Are you thinking of this in terms of a Hamel basis, not Schauder?

Comment: I would say Hamel. I mean, I am talking about the algebraic codimension of a vector subspace.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. I was a bit perplexed since most people talk about dimension in the Schauder sense since algebraic dimension is kind of terrible hah.